# Is stencil command on Unity used only for making pixels invisible or is it more?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, stencil-buffer

I want to have an object which is greyed out (grayscale) when it is inside a specific mesh. For now, I have followed some videos and used the stencil command in shader to make it invisible inside (or outside) the mesh but this is not what I quite want.

How can I make it so the object will be seen as it is when inside a specific mesh renderer and have a grayscale effect when outside it? Is it possible to do that using stencil on Unity shaders?

Answer (score 1):

[Unity - Sharderlab - Stencil](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html)

> The stencil buffer stores an 8-bit integer value for each pixel
> in the frame buffer. Before executing the **fragment shader**
> for a given **pixel**, the GPU can **compare the current value** in the stencil buffer against a **given reference value**. This is called a stencil test. If the stencil test passes, the GPU performs the depth test. If the stencil test **fails**, the GPU **skips the rest of the processing for that pixel**. This means that you can use the stencil buffer as a mask to tell the GPU which pixels to draw, and which pixels to discard.

and in general more about it e.g. at [Wikipedia - Stencil Buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_buffer).

In very simplified words: Basically it is used to tell the Shader passes to not overwrite certain pixels based on given conditions and allows them to write a certain value to the stencil buffer for the rendered pixels themselves.

[See Through Objects with Stencil Buffers using Unity URP](https://theslidefactory.com/see-through-objects-with-stencil-buffers-using-unity-urp/) is a good explanation and example use case.

---

For your specific use case

> How can I make it so the object will be seen as it is when inside a specific mesh renderer and have a grayscale effect when outside it?

you might want to have a look at [Creating Overlap Shader Effects, Such as Underwater and Night Vision, in Unity's Shader Graph](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/creating-overlap-underwater-night-vision-effects-in-shader-graph) which rather uses the ShaderGraph and a Depth test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really appreciated it! Although the article you have sent the link of doesn't quite do what I want. It is close but I want the effect to be reversed. I want to have effects when outside, not inside.